# Asp.Net MVC Ajax.ActionLink behaivour different when using built in VS2008 dev server to IIS hosted

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, ajax, iis, iis-7

This is a really strange issue. I have developed a small MVC application and have done testing up until now using the VS2008 built in dev server and everything works as I expect. I have now moved the solution to IIS hosted and I see different results in a view which uses an Ajax.ActionLink.

The actionlink links to a controller action which returns a partial view (.ascx). In the AjaxOptions of the link I specify the UpdateTargetId of the DOM element that I wish the partial view returned by the action to replace. When running the application using the built in dev server, behaviour is as expected -> the ajax call successfully returns the partialview and replaces the specified DOM element. However when hosted in IIS, the controller action is successfully executed but the result is rendered on a new page rather than replacing the specifed DOM element.

Here is relevant source for the page which makes the ajax call:

```
<% if (info.CurrentStatus != OrderStatus.Received &&
              info.CurrentStatus != OrderStatus.Processing)
           { %>
                <td><%= Ajax.ActionLink("Reprocess Order", "Reprocess",
                            new { generatedId = info.GeneratedId },
                            new AjaxOptions
                            {
                                UpdateTargetId = "success" + info.GeneratedId,
                                OnSuccess = "reprocessSuccess"
                            })%></td>
        <% } %>

        <td><%= Html.Div("success" + info.GeneratedId) %> </td>
```

And here is the action which provides the partial view:

```
[RequiresSearch()]
public ActionResult Reprocess(string generatedId)
{
    if (RequestReprocessingOfOrder(generatedId))
    {
        ViewData["reprocessSuccess"] = "Reprocessing request successful. Order is queued for reprocessing";
    }
    else
    {
        ViewData["reprocessSuccess"] = "Reprocessing request failed. Please contact the administrator";
    }

    return PartialView();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

**EDIT:** I don't have alot of mvc/ajax experience so am unsure as to where to event start to try and solve this, so even pointers of what to look for would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I have solved this problem, turned out to be caused by the src references I was using for the scripts the view required (in this case MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftMvcAjax.js). The path I was using was no longer valid when hosted in IIS, so dynamically generating the path solved the issue.

Replace:

```
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

With:

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")%>" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")%>" type="text/javascript"/>
```

Silly mistake, but solution not obvious considering the symptoms.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.  I spent hours messing around with this until I saw your post here.  Thanks!